# PDO uncaught error posting form data

Tags: php, mysql, forms

struggling to see what the error is here, trying to submit some fields into the db with a password salt also its to add new users to my site (I will be improving the security) but struggling a bit as I am getting the correct results with `var_dump` please see below as I cannot spot the issue?

Here is the form:

```
<form action="actions/add_emp.php" method="post">

  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" required="required"  /><br/>
  <input type="text" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="Password"/></label><br/>

    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="name" required="required" placeholder="Firstname"/><br />
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="email" required="required" placeholder="Lastname"/><br/>
    <input type="email" name="emailAddress" id="city" required="required" placeholder="Email Address"/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="extension" id="extension" required="required" placeholder="Extension Number"/><br/>
    <select name="title">
        <option  selected disabled>Please Select a Job Title...</option>

        <option disabled></option>
        <option disabled>Helpesk:</option>
        <option value="Technical Support Advisor">Technical Support Advisor</option>
        <option value="Deputy Team Leade">Deputy Team Leader</option>
        <option value="Team Leader">Team Leader</option>
        <option value="Incident Resolution Advisor">Incident Resolution Advisor</option>

        <option disabled></option>
        <option disabled>Call Centre:</option>
        <option value="Technical Support Advisor">Technical Support Advisor</option>
        <option value="">Deputy Team Leader</option>
        <option value="">Team Leader</option>

        <option disabled></option>
    </select>
    <br><br> 
    <input type="submit" value="Add User" name="submit"/><br />
</form>
```

Here is the action script:

```
 <?
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include_once'../../config.php';

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=dashboardr",$username,$password);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

    if(isset($_POST['user']) && isset($_POST['pass'])){
    $password=$_POST['pass'];
    $sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `user_login` WHERE `username`=?");
    $sql->execute(array($_POST['user']));

    if($sql->fetchColumn()!=0){

    die("User Exists");

    }else{
     function rand_string($length) {
      $str="";
      $chars = "MY SALT LIVES HERE - NOT THE MOST SECURE I KNOW!";
      $size = strlen($chars);
      for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
       $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
      }

      return $str; 
     }
     $p_salt = rand_string(20); 
     $site_salt="MYCUSTOMSALT"; 
     $salted_hash = hash('sha256', $password.$site_salt.$p_salt);

     $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `emailAddress`, `extension`) 
                            VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, '".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["lastname"]."','".$_POST["emailAddress"]."','".$_POST["extension"]."';");

var_dump($sql); 
     $sql->execute(array($_POST['user'], $salted_hash, $p_salt));

     header ('Location: ../list_emp.php');


    }
   }
  }
  ?>
```

I am fairly new to PDO so I am still learning.

Oh and here is the result from the var_dump:

```
object(PDOStatement)#3 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(203) "INSERT INTO `user_login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `emailAddress`, `extension`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, 'firstname','lastname','email@email.com','1234';" }
```

Here is the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/admin/actions/add_emp.php:72 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/admin/actions/add_emp.php(72): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/dashboardr v3.2.3/admin/actions/add_emp.php on line 72

Comment: What are you even doing with your prepared statement?  Did you just copy and paste and hope for the best?   You start using parameters then just give up?  Putting a $_POST variable in your prepared statement leaves it open to injection attacks.

Comment: Hey I am new ti this dont flame me dude I need some pointers im not asking for an answer I am fully aware this isnt secure and isn't the best approach but that is why I need some pros eyes on it so I can get better

Comment: try removing trailing `;` from your `INSERT` query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you don't have a closing parenthesis on the query.

```
INSERT INTO `user_login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `emailAddress`, `extension`)
VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, 'firstname','lastname','email@email.com','1234';
```

Needs to be

```
INSERT INTO `user_login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `emailAddress`, `extension`)
VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, 'firstname','lastname','email@email.com','1234');
```

But your code has more serious concerns.  You are using a prepared statement wrong.  More to follow....

You never put user input directly into the query.  This is a reason for prepared statements and parameters.  You use the placeholders `?` and then bind the parameters later in the execute statement like so:

```
 $sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `user_login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `psalt`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `emailAddress`, `extension`) 
                        VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $sql->execute(
   array($_POST['user'], $salted_hash, $p_salt, $_POST["firstname"], $_POST["lastname"], $_POST["emailAddress"], $_POST["extension"])
 );
```

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense, I wasn't far off it just gets me confused sometimes, its good that you have taken time to explain it to me :)

Comment: @phpcoder, glad I could help.   Sorry if I seemed to flame you, I just deal with a lot of people who copy and paste, change it, and then ask why something doesn't work instead of actually learning to code properly.  It would do you some good to study the functions you use at php.net, they are all well documented with examples.

Comment: this was copied and pasted but from something else inside of my own scripts but I did actually spot the error after posting it but in turn it was great that you shown me the correct use of prepared statements I am currently going through all of my database hooks to ensure they are handling the inserts properly. Thank you.